# What to use in iOS to show message at scheduled times?

Tags: ios, swift, reminders, scheduledexecutorservice

I suppose that my question is too broad, but I can not figure out how to make app in iOS which can show on screen messages (like reminder) on specific (scheduled) times.

As far as I understand there are no services in iOS like in Android.

I need to show text and play sound.

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: `UILocalNotification`, or Apple Push Notification ?

Comment: I want to initiate showing messages internally on iPhone. May be I am wrong but APN needs external service. But as I see `UILocalNotification` is supposed to do the work. 10x for reply.

Comment: Hi We do not have anything like services in android, so there is no possibility to run your code when application is in terminated state except few cases. new2ios's idea of @UILocalNotification is good to notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

I use NSTimer()

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: "upload", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Above example will call method `upload()` every 10 seconds. You can read more about it at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

Comment: Ok, but I want the message to be shown even the application is not active. Is this possible with `NSTimer`?

Comment: You can use background fetch https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Comment: background modes have different purpose all together. I don't think it is suitable for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use `UILocalNotification`. first add the following line to your app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```swift
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))
//you can change the type to badge, sound, etc...
```

then use the following method to fire your notification ...

```swift
func sendLocalNotToAwakenUI(){
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Some text..." // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.alertAction = "open" // text that is displayed after "slide to..." on the lock screen - defaults to "slide to view"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate() // todo item due date (when notification will be fired, currently set to RIGHT NOW)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound
//        notification.userInfo = ["UUID": item.UUID, ] // assign a unique identifier to the notification so that we can retrieve it later
    notification.category = "TODO_CATEGORY"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

and you can receive a callback in app delegate with the following...

```swift
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("RECIEVED CALLBACK")
}
```